# ngTable in Angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, bower

I am using the ngtable in my angularjs application but when doing grunt build, the references are missed and it shows error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module parts360App due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngTable due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngTable' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=ngTable
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:66:12
```

The table i am using - http://ng-table.com/#/

```
bower install ng-table --save
```

bower.json gets updated but the reference for the table is unavailable in the index.html

I also tried with npm but it shows an error on command prompt:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular@^1.2
`-- ng-table@3.0.1

npm WARN ng-table@3.0.1 requires a peer of angular@^1.2 but none was installed.
```

This is my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "parts360",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "angular-busy": "^4.1.4",
    "ng-table": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "parts360App",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest how to resolve this to get the references in index.html

like others:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-busy/dist/angular-busy.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->

    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately ng-table is not supported anymore on bower.

You can find all the UpToDate [installations methods](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table#installing) on their github.

If you really want / have to use bower, you can use :

```
bower install ng-table-bundle
```

and add the reference to it, as other bower components :

```
<script src="bower_components/ng-table-bundle/ng-table.min.js"></script>
```